# flash object wmode transparent in google chrome distorts text

Tags: flash, google-chrome, wmode

I'm having a difficult time trying to make a trasparent flash clip work as it should in google chrome. Whenever I use wmode = "transparent" the text in the clip gets distorted and pixelated. While this does not happen in firefox nor IE.

My code looks like:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="myClip" name="myClip" align="middle" data="myClip.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">            
</object>
```

I'm using Version 33.0.1750.146 m of Chrome

Am I missing some parameter that Chrome requires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the textfield property Anti-alias to "Anti-alias for animation". Also check if the font was embedded.

Avoid set the wmode to transparent since is not very good for performance. You can check more information at: [wmode - What does it mean in browser's rendering behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402262/wmode-what-does-it-mean-in-browsers-rendering-behavior)

Comment: I solved it by embedding the font. Thanks!! (Funny how IE and Firefox displayed it correctly though..)